# Creation of multi page TIFF in an applet

Tags: java, applet, tiff, jai

I have a list of images and would like to create a multi-page TIFF with them. I know [it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165792/how-to-combine-two-or-many-tiff-image-files-in-to-one-multipage-tiff-image-in-ja?lq=1) using JAI but since its jar is quite big (9mb, on windows) i rather not use it, if possible (i do not like the idea of forcing the user to download 9mb of *extra* stuff).

Are there alternatives? Is it possible to get a *lite* (with reduced size) version of JAI, without all the features i'm not going to use?

Comment: Depending of your environment 9mb might not be too much. If it is intended for enterprise environment (or even for internet environment where users visit often), think that the jars will be cached so only the first loading will be heavy.

Comment: It's an enterprise environment but there are two things that bother me: a) the rest of the app (libs and my code) weigths just 3mb and b) 9mb could take some time to load (even if only for the first time)

Answer (score 0):

For know i resolved the issue by using the platform indipendent version of JAI, as it only weigths 2mb. I lost the hardware acceleration but it's not an issue in this case.